# Jquery draggable time bar events

Tags: jquery, slider, draggable

I have a time bar of events. It works so that when sliding the time pin from the slidebar, the image slider moves back and forth in time. The same happens when dragging the image slider itself, with the slidebar at the bottom sliding at the same time and showing what year we are on. I have found a fiddle from somewhere else, I've modified it and reused it as I needed but I can't figure out how to

1) make the bottom sidebar start from 1902 until 2014 without conflicting with the image slider

2) when dragging the image slider around, I need the bottom slidebar to slide accordingly towords the appropriate date.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V3dFy/ and here is the js:

```
$(function(){
//vars
var conveyor = $(".content-conveyor", $("#sliderContent")),
item = $(".item", $("#sliderContent"));

//set length of conveyor
conveyor.css("width", item.length * parseInt(item.css("width")));

var max = (item.length * parseInt(item.css("width"))) - parseInt($(".viewer", $("#sliderContent")).css("width"));
var min = parseInt($(".viewer", $("#sliderContent")).css("width"));

//config
var sliderOpts = {
  max: max,
  min: min,
  step: 5,
  slide: function(e, ui) { 
    conveyor.css("left", "-" + ui.value + "px");
    tooltip.text(ui.value);
  }
};

$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",  
    containment: [-850, 0, 650, 0],
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(e, ui){
        $("#slider").slider(sliderOpts);
    }
});

var tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();

//create slider
$("#slider").slider(sliderOpts).find(".ui-slider-handle").append(tooltip).hover(function() {
    tooltip.show()
}, function() {
    tooltip.hide()
});
});
```

Please can anyone help? I've spent the past 2 days trying to figuring it out but my js skills are not that good. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Jeff